# Angular ng-repeat orderBy and groupBy not ordering properly

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-orderby

i'm using angular's `ng-repeat` with `groupBy` and `orderBy`.
What I'm trying to achieve is ordering by SeatNo ie; 1, 2, 8, 12 but what Angular gives me is 1, 12, 2, 8.

***PS***: I know that SeatNo is a string and have tried `parseInt` but that doesn't seem to work

html

```
<tbody ng-if="::!isOnlyAllSeat" ng-repeat="(key, value) in billRaw | groupBy: 'SeatNo' | orderBy: 'SeatNo' track by key">
  <tr class="right bg-darkBlue fg-white">
    <td colspan="{{::colSpan}}"> Seat {{key==0?"ALL":key}}</td>
    <td class="right bill-col-5"><span class="label bg-white fg-black place-right">{{value.length}}</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="item in value  | orderBy: 'ClassCode' " class="fg-darkBlue">
    <td class="bill-col-1 middle">{{item.ClassCode}}</td>
    <td class="text-left bill-col-2 middle">
      <span class="">{{item.Name}}</span>
      <div class="note-tag-list" ng-if="item.Options">
        <div class="note-tag-item note-tag" ng-repeat="question in item.Options track by question.Question_ID">
          <div ng-repeat="option in question.Options track by option.Option_ID">
            <a href class="label info note-tag">{{option.Option}}
              <small class="price-tag" ng-if="option.ActualPrice !== '0.00'">+{{option.ActualPrice | currency}}</small>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="text-left bill-col-5 middle">
      <div>{{item.ActualPrice | currency}}</div>
      <div><small ng-if="item.OptionsTotalActualPrice !== 0">+{{item.OptionsTotalActualPrice | currency}} : Add-on </small></div>
      <div ng-if="item.DiscountAmt>0"><span class="fg-red">({{( getDiscount(item) | currency)}})</span> : {{((item.ActionTypeID == 1)? item.DiscountAmt+'% OFF':item.CodeName)}}</div>
      <div ng-if="item.ActionTypeID == 1">{{item.CodeName}}</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

here is my `billRaw` array.

***Note -*** it is sorted by SeatNo

```
[
 {"OrderItemID": "329277",
  "Name": "Mexican Tacos",
  "Delivered": "0",
  "ShortName": "MEXICAN TACOS",
  "Price": "8.0000",
  "MenuItemID": "2318",
  "SeatNo": "1",
  "SequenceNo": "37",
  "AlcoholCheck": "0",
  "OStatusID": "2",
  "Notes": "",
  "Options": [],
  "OptionsTotal": 0,
  "OptionsTotalActualPrice": 0,
  "ActualPrice": "8.00",
  "CodeID": 0,
  "DiscountAmt": 0,
  "ActionTypeID": 0,
  "CodeName": 0,
  "ReductionType": 0,
  "PayerSeq": "0",
  "PriceType_ID": "1",
  "ParentClassName": "Tacos",
  "NetPrice": 8,
  "ExtItem_ID": "J9X79NS28M1ZY",
  "ExtOrderItem_ID": null,
  "Code": null
 },
{
  "OrderItemID": "329278",
  "Name": "Mexican Tacos",
  "Delivered": "0",
  "ShortName": "MEXICAN TACOS",
  "Price": "8.0000",
  "MenuItemID": "2318",
  "SeatNo": "2",
  "SequenceNo": "38",
  "AlcoholCheck": "0",
  "OStatusID": "2",
  "Notes": "",
  "Options": [],
  "OptionsTotal": 0,
  "OptionsTotalActualPrice": 0,
  "ActualPrice": "8.00",
  "CodeID": 0,
  "DiscountAmt": 0,
  "ActionTypeID": 0,
  "CodeName": 0,
  "ReductionType": 0,
  "PayerSeq": "0",
  "PriceType_ID": "1",
  "ParentClassName": "Tacos",
  "NetPrice": 8,
  "ExtItem_ID": "J9X79NS28M1ZY",
  "ExtOrderItem_ID": null,
  "Code": null
 },
 {
  "OrderItemID": "329276",
  "Name": "Mexican Tacos",
  "Delivered": "0",
  "ShortName": "MEXICAN TACOS",
  "Price": "8.0000",
  "MenuItemID": "2318",
  "SeatNo": "8",
  "SequenceNo": "36",
  "AlcoholCheck": "0",
  "OStatusID": "2",
  "Notes": "",
  "Options": [],
  "OptionsTotal": 0,
  "OptionsTotalActualPrice": 0,
  "ActualPrice": "8.00",
  "CodeID": 0,
  "DiscountAmt": 0,
  "ActionTypeID": 0,
  "CodeName": 0,
  "ReductionType": 0,
  "PayerSeq": "0",
  "PriceType_ID": "1",
  "ParentClassName": "Tacos",
  "NetPrice": 8,
  "ExtItem_ID": "J9X79NS28M1ZY",
  "ExtOrderItem_ID": null,
  "Code": null
 },
 {
  "OrderItemID": "329275",
  "Name": "Mexican Tacos",
  "Delivered": "0",
  "ShortName": "MEXICAN TACOS",
  "Price": "8.0000",
  "MenuItemID": "2318",
  "SeatNo": "12",
  "SequenceNo": "35",
  "AlcoholCheck": "0",
  "OStatusID": "2",
  "Notes": "",
  "Options": [],
  "OptionsTotal": 0,
  "OptionsTotalActualPrice": 0,
  "ActualPrice": "8.00",
  "CodeID": 0,
  "DiscountAmt": 0,
  "ActionTypeID": 0,
  "CodeName": 0,
  "ReductionType": 0,
  "PayerSeq": "0",
  "PriceType_ID": "1",
  "ParentClassName": "Tacos",
  "NetPrice": 8,
  "ExtItem_ID": "J9X79NS28M1ZY",
  "ExtOrderItem_ID": null,
  "Code": null
 }
]
```

***Edit***

I have modified billRaw so that `type` of SeatNo is `number` . but it still doesn't work

```
_.forEach($scope.billRaw, function(value,key) {
     value.SeatNo = parseInt(value.SeatNo);
});
```

Comment: It is string value hence ordering it that way. You would need to convert it to int as you said. Why isn't parseInt working?

Comment: `parseInt ` on `orderBy` has no effect and `parseInt` on `groupBy` just gives the array indices 0, 1, 2, 3.

Comment: How do you parse it, you should be doing it on actual json array before doing orderBy.

Comment: I have changed the SeatNo to int
          ` _.forEach($scope.billRaw, function(value,key) {
                value.SeatNo = parseInt(value.SeatNo);
           });`
           but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can try running

```
$.each(billRaw, function(i) {billRaw[i].SeatNo = parseInt(billRaw[i].SeatNo)});
```

in the controller, which will convert the SeatNos to numbers. Then it should work fine.

Comment: i've changed the type of SeatNo to number . but it still doesn't work

Comment: Try removing groupby clause